# post view count not incrementing on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

in my show livewire components I'm trying to record the view count and also make it unique so that when a user or guest Refresh the count won't increase, but the issue is that the count isn't incrementing , how can I solve this

```
public function increment() {
        $this->view_count++;
    }
    public function mount(Post $post, $votesCount)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->votesCount = $votesCount;
        $this->hasVoted = $post->isVotedByUser(auth()->user());

        if(Cookie::get($post->id)!=''){
            Cookie::set('$post->id', '1', 60);
         $post->increment();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the `$post` model object after increment.

Something like this:

```php
public function incrementCount() 
{
    $this->view_count++;
    $this->save();
}
```

there is an alternative and simpler way too:

```php
public function incrementCount() 
{
    $this->increment('view_count');
}
```

Comment: that's didn't work still not incrementing

Comment: @kiki I renamed the function, try with new code.

Comment: @kiki Also, these functions should be inside your Model!

Comment: oh I was adding it into my livewire components , I'm going to try it now